# Good code practice for variable assignment using a condition

Tags: ruby

I had this code:

```
if @locale
    HighVoltage.content_path = "#{@template_to_use}/pages/#{@locale}/"
else
    HighVoltage.content_path = 'pages/'
end
```

Now I have this version:

```
HighVoltage.content_path = @locale ?
    "#{@template_to_use}/pages/#{@locale}/" :
    'pages/'
```

What would be the suggested way to write this piece of code, first or second version or may be other

Comment: If it's going to be on separate lines, don't use ternary.

Comment: Good question, and ok, so it's not suppose to use ternary, but on his first example its calling twice `HighVolage.content_path` its not a DRY?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa, it's not that much of a problem. If you really want to be DRY at all costs, you can `x = if[...]end`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my opinion here is the best option:

```
HighVoltage.content_path = 
  if @locale
    "#{@template_to_use}/pages/#{@locale}/"
  else
    'pages/'
  end
```

You don't repeat yourself with `HighVoltage.content_path =` as in the first example that you have provided. **BUT** some people do find my approach to look a little bit ugly compared to this one. So you could use it if you believe the same.

You better not to use `A ? B : C` statement if it will take multiple lines.

See https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#use-if-case-returns for further reference.

Comment: Could you please explain why it is better than the other 2 approaches?

Comment: this is what is recommended by the ruby style guides, but with a bit different identation: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#use-if-case-returns

Comment: @ArnoldRoa Nice edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the ruby style guide this is prefered

```
HighVoltage.content_path =
  if @locale
    "#{@template_to_use}/pages/#{@locale}/"
  else
    'pages/'
  end
```

https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#use-if-case-returns

Comment: That's talking about a nested ternary. There's no nested ternary in this question.

Comment: The style says  that maxim reply is the correct, but with a different identation check this: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#use-if-case-returns

Comment: Ok I will edit my response accordingly

Comment: Ok now this reply is the right one! :)

Comment: This is about using `HighVoltage.content_path` twice. It doesn't say anything about the ternary.

Comment: @ArnoldRoa, what's the difference with Maxim's answer?

Comment: I have edited my and Maxim's answer to say effectively the same thing now. I believe both are correct.

Comment: Since they are the same you might as well delete yours.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a single line for the ternary?

```
HighVoltage.content_path = @locale ? "#{@template_to_use}/pages/#{@locale}/" : 'pages/'
```

I think either is readable and its just a matter of preference... If you want to have less lines of code go for the ternary option, if you like the readability of the first option then use that.

Comment: This is considered bad according to the ruby style guide.

Comment: Limit lines to 80 chars: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#80-character-limits

Comment: Simply because the line is long.

Comment: Ohh gotcha. I would say Maxim Pontyushenko 's answer is the best then.

.. or change the "@template_to_use" to just "@template" ... 81 characters so close lol